# Cakephp3 getting records of today only

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I want to get all the records from the table that were added today.

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
    $samples = TableRegistry::get('samples');

    $date = new DateTime('-1 days');

    $samples_data = $samples->find()
        ->contain(['Users'])
        ->where([
            "Samples.created >" => $date->format('d/m/Y')
        ]);
    debug($samples_data);
```

But it returns me all the samples. I don't understand what's the problem. 
If i don't format the date with `->format('d/m/y');` 
for example:

```
->where([
            "Samples.created >" => new DateTime('-1 days')
        ]);
```

It gives me an error that unable to convert datetime object to string.

[image]

Any help would save my day.

Comment: Why don't you use a proper date/time type for the `created` column?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Given the error that you mentioned, your `created` column is of a [character type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html), not a [date/time type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html). If that's not the case, please mention the actual type, and ensure that you've cleared your model cache. btw, whenever receiving errors, please always post the complete error message including the full stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it it is available in a properly readable fashion)!

Comment: Please see the updated question

Comment: How can i use created field as object?

Comment: By changing your column to a date/time type.

Comment: That is already datetime in my database

Comment: Please re-read my second comment. I asked you to mention that if that is the case, and to make sure that you have cleared your model cache. Also such a half-cut stacktrace is not overly helpful, and knowing what DBMS you are using also wouldn't hurt, from the format I would have thought you're using Postgres. And why do you create duplicates of this question? That's kinda rude.

Comment: I'm sorry i did'nt mentioned, i'm using mysql for this. On the other question I've asked about the documentation that isnt working on my end.